# Quotient Ring by Nilradical

Tags: commutative-algebra, solution-verification

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $\mathcal{N}$ its nilradical (i.e., the set of all nilpotent elements of $R$). The proposition I'm trying to prove is that $\mathcal{N}$ is an ideal of $R$ and $R/\mathcal{N}$ has no non null nilpotent.

The first part is simple, I've proven it. The second part is the one I'm not secure with.

What I'm thinking to do is to suppose that $R/\mathcal{N}$ has a non null nilpotent $\overline{n}$ and take the ideal $\overline{\mathcal{M}} = \langle\overline{n}\rangle$ generated by it. Then I'll use the Ideal Correspondence Theorem to show that $\mathcal{M}=\pi^{-1}(\overline{\mathcal{M}})\supsetneq\mathcal{N}$ contains at least one nilpotent element $n$ such that $n\notin\mathcal{N}$. Contradiction.

So, *q.e.d.*?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too complicated.  If $x+ \mathcal N$ is nilpotent, then $x^n + \mathcal N = 0 + \mathcal N$ for some $n \geq 1$.  That means $x^n \in \mathcal N$.  That means $x \in \mathcal N$ (why?).

Comment: Because it's nilpotent